# Django url template tag returns encoded url

Tags: python, django, url

When using Django's {% url %} template tag, I am getting unexpected results. 
I am looking to get a url such as:

```
domain.com/create_placement/<id>
```

instead the following is returned:

```
domain.com/organizations/<id>/%7B%%20url%20'create_placement'%20org_id=organization.id%20%%3E
```

#### My Code:

*template.py*

```
...
<a href="{% url 'create_placement' organization.id %>">Create Placement</a>  
...
```

*views.py*

```
def create_placement(request, org_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        organization = Organization.objects.get(id=org_id)

        ## Gather post data
        placement_form = PlacementForm(request.POST)

        ## Validate Form
        if placement_form.is_valid():
            ## Send to database
            placement_form.save()

            ## redirect to placement view
            placement = Placement.objects.latest('id')
            return redirect('individual_organization', id=placement.id)            

    else:
        placement_form = PlacementForm(initial = { "organization" : organization})

    return render(request, "admin_tracking/create_placement.html", {'placement_form': placement_form})
```

*urls.py*

```
url(r'^create_placement/(?P<org_id>\d+)$', views.create_placement, name="create_placement"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the ending `%>`

```
{% url 'create_placement' organization.id %>
```

should be

```
{% url 'create_placement' organization.id %}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.  I've been looking over that for hours